# Java Extends RuntimeException filed value is thread safe?

Tags: java

Help me my Simple question.

here is my simple exception.

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {

private MyErrors error;

public MyException() {
}

public MyException(String message) {
    super(message);
}


public MyException(MyErrors error) {
    super(error.getMessage());
    this.error = error;
}
```

}

```
    public class MyService {

...

    public String someMethod(String id){
        Optional<Prizes> prize = Optional.ofNullable(prizesRepository.findById(id));

        if(prize.isPresent()){
            return prize.get().getPrize();
        }
        throw new MyException(ThanksGivenErrors.BadRequest);

    }
}
```

this is MyController used MyService

```
public class MyController{


...

@PostMapping("/prize")
public ResponseEntity findPrize(@RequestParam String id) {
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(MyService.someMethod(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (MyException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getError().getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

}

MyService is a Spring bean and singleton.

I thought that the value of the 'error' field in MyException might change if MyService is used in a multithreaded environment and many MyException occur.

Is the field value of 'MyException(extends RuntimeException)' 'thread safe'?

I do not think it will be safe.
Thank you for your teaching.

Comment: It'll be safe if you make the field `final`. But why would you share an exception across threads?

Comment: @shmosel that won't make it thread safe. The only way to have thread safe objects is that the object is immutable, and this depends on the design of the class. For example, if you have a `final List<String> errorDetails = new ArrayList<>();` attribute, it doesn't matter if `errorDetails` is marked as `final` because `ArrayList` is a mutable instance of a `List`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It depends what you mean by thread-safety.

Comment: @shmosel simple, that an object state cannot be modified by another thread. If, for example, using reflection I may alter the state of an object that is shared between threads, then the object is not thread safe.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's certainly a valid definition. It wasn't the one I was using.

Comment: @shmosel
I sent a message through 'MyException' to 'MyController' using 'MyService.someMethod (..)' to tell it that 'someMethod' failed.

Comment: Is this a bad way to do this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to say. Are you not throwing the exception? Where does the other thread enter the picture?

Comment: @shmosel
i writed MyController code

Comment: I'm not seeing any cross-thread sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter mentioned, you can make your exception thread-safe by using the `final` keyword, assuming that `MyErrors` is thread-safe as well.

However, you should note that your concern that

> the value of the 'error' field in MyException might change if MyService is used in a multithreaded environment and many MyException occur.

Is not valid here. There is no need for your exception to be thread safe because even when the exception is thrown, it will only ever be available to the throwing thread. Since `MyException` appears to be a runtime exception, you don't appear to be propagating the exception, so it doesn't look like you will be sharing the state of the exception anywhere once it has been thrown.

I recommend that you keep the exception non-thread-safe if that is the case.

Comment: I would highlight *assuming that `MyErrors` is thread-safe as well*

Comment: Oh thank God.
'There is no need for your exception to be thread safe because even when the exception is thrown, it will only be available to the throwing thread'
I got what I did not know.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*RuntimeException* extends from *Throwable* which is not thread-safe or immutable. It has methods which change the state such as :
[addSuppressed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable))